# Visual Studio 2013 Express Folder Workaround

Tags: visual-studio-2013, project

Has anyone found a workaround to create solution folders in VS2013 Express (Desktop)? VS prices are obviously too expensive for an indie dev ._.

Comment: What do you mean by *create folders*? Which flavour of VS Express are you talking about? (Web, Phone, etc.)

Comment: I suspect the OP means solution folders

Comment: edited. VS for Windows Desktop

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to achieve - do you need this folder to be under source control? Do you need constant access from the solution explorer? Maybe using the Source Control Explorer could be a workaround.

Comment: for src control would be one big point, but for this i think I can just create folders by hand. Idk If the project still works if I try to pull it. I think it won't

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Solution Folder in Visual Studio Express 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19949972/create-solution-folder-in-visual-studio-express-2013)

Comment: well when I try this solution, my .sln gets corrupted